# Proving $f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, differential

Let $f$ be a function defined on $[a,b]$ so that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differential on $(a,b)$, $f(a)=0$ and there exist a real number $A$ so that
$$|f'(x)| \leq A |f(x)|$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Comment: This is not true. These conditions are satisfied by $f(x)=c$ for any constant $c$.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true.  Try this $a = 0$, $b = 1$, $f(x) = 1$ so $f'(x) = 0$ and $A$ can be any positive number or even $0$.

Comment: The problem appears to be incorrect. Take $f = e^x$. All conditions are satisfied for some suitable interval, and A =1.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, one condition is missing

Comment: I've just editted it

Comment: @NguyễnQuangAnh: Then your question is a duplicate (see links in previous comments), it has been asked and answered before.

Comment: The previous proof requires using $log|f(x)|$ but we can not be sure if there is some $x$ that $f(x)=0$ or not

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f(x),f'(x)>0$, we can write

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-A\le0$$ and by integration

$$\log f(x)-Ax-B=\log\frac{f(x)}{e^{AX+B}}$$ must be decreasing.

Many functions fulfill this condition.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it